# How to create Certificate and Issuer with Python Kubernetes Client

Tags: python, kubernetes

I want to create the following two objects in Kubernetes using the [python kubernetes-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python).

```yaml
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: test-selfsigned
  namespace: cert-manager-test
spec:
  selfSigned: {}
---
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: selfsigned-cert
  namespace: cert-manager-test
spec:
  dnsNames:
    - example.com
  secretName: selfsigned-cert-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: test-selfsigned
```

The documentation does not show any examples on how to create objects for `apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1`. I tried to deploy this with [utils.create_from_yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/utils/create_from_yaml.py), but that doesn't allow me to create these objects.

Any help on this? Please share a working code snippet that can be used.